# Truncate Table sometimes takes seconds and sometimes does not finish in 2 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL command `Truncate Table` usually completes in seconds. But sometimes it does not finish in 2 minutes and the truncation session is not blocked by any other sessions.

Comment: Wow - I believe you but that has never happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely due to indexes being updated during the truncate operation.

It is often faster to drop all indexes, truncate, and re-apply indexes once the table is empty.

Note: in case you aren't aware, truncate is not logged, there's no going back once you do this (which may be intentional).

Comment: AFAIK, truncate table is just marking data pages as unused, why having index could affect performance?

Comment: When marking data pages why it needs to update index. As I've read, truncate table is more like DDL, not any data manipulation. I don't have deep knowledge about it but I'll do some research just to know the concept. if you have any useful article, I appreciate if you share with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could also be due to a row or table lock or an open transaction.

Comment: This looks like to be a comment